# How do I determine whether a Perl file handle is a read or write handle?

Tags: perl, filehandle

You are given either an `IO::File` object or a typeglob (`\*STDOUT` or `Symbol::symbol_to_ref("main::FH")`); how would you go about determining if it is a read or write handle?  The interface cannot be extended to pass this information (I am overriding `close` to add calls to `flush` and `sync` before the actual close).

Currently I am attempting to `flush` and `sync` the filehandle and ignoring the error `"Invalid argument"` (which is what I get when I attempt to `flush` or `sync` a read filehandle):

```
eval { $fh->flush; 1 } or do {
        #this seems to exclude flushes on read handles
        unless ($! =~ /Invalid argument/) {
                croak "could not flush $fh: $!";
        }
};

eval { $fh->sync; 1 } or do {
        #this seems to exclude syncs on read handles
        unless ($! =~ /Invalid argument/) {
                croak "could not sync $fh: $!";
        }
};
```

Comment: +1 Fantastic question! I have no idea when I would ever use this, but I'm fascinated to know someone needs this.

Comment: Ext4 has brought up problems that Ext3 had kept hidden for a while.  See http://thunk.org/tytso/blog/2009/03/15/dont-fear-the-fsync/ and the ongoing p5p thread (http://www.xray.mpe.mpg.de/mailing-lists/perl5-porters/2009-03/msg00322.html) for background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the fcntl options.  Maybe `F_GETFL` with `O_ACCMODE`.

**Edit:** I did a little googling and playing over lunch and here is some *probably non-portable* code but it works for my Linux box, and probably any Posix system (perhaps even Cygwin, who knows?).

```
use strict;
use Fcntl;
use IO::File;

my $file;
my %modes = ( 0 => 'Read only', 1 => 'Write only', 2 => 'Read / Write' );

sub open_type {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $mode = fcntl($fh, F_GETFL, 0);
    print "File is: " . $modes{$mode & 3} . "\n";
}

print "out\n";
$file = new IO::File();
$file->open('> /tmp/out');
open_type($file);

print "\n";

print "in\n";
$file = new IO::File();
$file->open('< /etc/passwd');
open_type($file);

print "\n";

print "both\n";
$file = new IO::File();
$file->open('+< /tmp/out');
open_type($file);
```

Example output:

```
$ perl test.pl 
out
File is: Write only

in
File is: Read only

both
File is: Read / Write
```

Comment: It looks like fcntl is OS specific, but if it works for a given OS, I might just build a dispatch hash based on the OS and fall back to my current code if the current OS is not in the dispatch hash.

Comment: Instead of hard coding '3' you could do `O_RDONLY | O_RDWR | O_WRONLY` but those constants are very unlikely to change since they haven't changed for like 20 years. Still, it makes the code more readable.

Comment: I have a access to OS X, Linux, FreeBSD, and WinXP; if it works on all of those then this might just be the answer.

Comment: It seems to work for IO::File objects, but not typeglobs, time to see how to upgrade a typeglob to IO::File.

Comment: Apparently I am on crack, it seems to work just fine for typeglobs, STDIN and STDOUT just seem to be marked as Read / Write.  When I use a file I open it just works.